# Why does Hibernate complain about being unable to load the authentication DLL even though its configured in Maven?

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, windows-10

I have a Java project in Windows with the following Maven config:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
        <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>10.2.0.jre8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
        <artifactId>mssql-jdbc_auth</artifactId>
        <version>10.2.0.x64</version>
        <type>dll</type>
    </dependency>
```

And the following Hibernate config:

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.url">
  jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=<DBNAME>;
  integratedSecurity=true;TrustServerCertificate=True;domain=<DOMAIN>
</property>
```

When running the application with `integratedSecurity=false`, everything works. However switching it to `true` results in the following errors:

```
    This driver is not configured for integrated authentication

    Unable to load authentication DLL
```

What's going wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out there's a [known bug](https://github.com/microsoft/mssql-jdbc/issues/1617) in the SQL Server JDBC driver where the Maven-provided DLL isn't used when switching to integrated authentication. Instead, JDBC tries to load the same DLL from:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-<version>\bin
```

Copying `mssql-jdbc_auth-10.2.0.x64.dll` to that folder resolved the problem and integrated authentication now works. Until Microsoft fixes this bug in their library, this seems to be the only option.